# Mongoose: Still getting warning from mongoose model FindByIdAndUpdate() after adding options like useNewUrlParse:true

Tags: node.js, database, express, mongoose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Zn2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzfPE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSaLS.png)
here is my code and still getting this error.
How can I solve this?

Comment: insted of images put the code here.

Comment: here is my mongoose connection code :
`mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost/todos", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connection Successful");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });`

Comment: ` router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const result = await Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      {
        $set: {
          status: "active",
        },
      },
      {
        new: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
      },
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).json({
            error: "There was a server side error!",
          });
        } else {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "Todo was updated successfully!",
          });
        }
      }
    );
    console.log(result);
  });`

Comment: your connection was successful with mongodb??

Comment: yes. connection is successfull

Answer (score 0):

if your version is the latest(greater than 6.0), then you should downgrade the version like 5.13.8